# Transition doesn't work on child component, but works when applied to the parent component

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, tailwind-css

I'm trying to animate the width of a div of a child component. My code is simple:

```
    export const OuterComponent = () => {
      const sidebarCtx = useContext(SidebarContext);
    
      const style =
        "w-[100px] h-[60px] transition-all duration-1000 bg-purple-900 text-2xl text-white " +
        (sidebarCtx.isOpen ? " w-[400px] " : "");
    
      const InnerComponent = ({ children }) => {
        return (
          <div className={style}> // if I apply style just to this div transition won't work anymore
            {children}
            <a>testing</a>
          </div>
        );
      };
    
      return (
        <div className={style}> // if I apply style here and remove the above style on the InnerComponent transition works OK as normal
          <InnerComponent />
        </div>
      );
    };
```

As explained in the code comments, the problem is that if I apply `style` to `InnerComponent` directly, the width change is not animated.

Comment: When you use the class on `InnerComponent`, even if there's no transition, does the width change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening since you have defined `InnerComponent` inside `OuterComponent`, it is reinitiated on each `OuterComponent` render, and that is probably messing with your animation.

try this:

```
 const InnerComponent = ({ children, classNames }) => {
        return (
          <div className={classNames}> // if I apply style just to this div transition won't work anymore
            {children}
            <a>testing</a>
          </div>
        );
      };

export const OuterComponent = () => {
      const sidebarCtx = useContext(SidebarContext);
    
      const classNames =
        "w-[100px] h-[60px] transition-all duration-1000 bg-purple-900 text-2xl text-white " +
        (sidebarCtx.isOpen ? " w-[400px] " : "");
    
    
      return (
        <div className={style}> // if I apply style here and remove the above style on the InnerComponent transition works OK as normal
          <InnerComponent classNames={classNames} />
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right. and your code worked. It was a silly mistake to define a component inside the other one. Thanks for your response bro

Comment: sure thing! Also if you havn't already, explore `styled-components`, instead of making css classes do all the heavy lifting. in the long run, it will make your life easier

Answer (score 1):

Through CSS you can just apply the transition to the parent element; then set overflow of the parent element to hidden. I think this should work.

Comment: You should add an example :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but u can try this.

```
const style =
    `w-[${sidebarCtx.isOpen ? 400 : 100}px] h-[60px] transition-all duration-1000 bg-purple-900 text-2xl text-white`.
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I mean no difference with the original code